# Magento override Adminhtml Customer Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, adminhtml, overrides

I have been trying to override magento(1.9) admin's customer controller with my controller. But even though I have followed the steps correctly, I couldn't override the customer controller. Following are my codes

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Aemulare_Customer>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Aemulare_Customer>
</modules>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Aemulare_Customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">
                        Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml
                    </Aemulare_Customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

My Controller(app/code/local/Aemulare/Customer/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerController.php)

```
    <?php

     require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php";

     class Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController {

      public function indexAction() {
         die("H");
      }
}
```

What might be the issue? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think there is space issue remove the space..

```
<Aemulare_Customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml</Aemulare_Customer>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. I never thought that would be a issue!

Answer (score 2):

Space is creating issue as magento compare text string between these tag. It should be like below.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Aemulare_Customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml</Aemulare_Customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Aemulare_Customer>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Aemulare_Customer>
</modules>
   <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Aemulare_Customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml</Aemulare_Customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**Controller file :**

> app/code/local/Aemulare/Customer/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomerController.php

and define the class:

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/CustomerController.php';
class Aemulare_Customer_Adminhtml_CustomerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die('a'); //just for testing
    }
}
```